# Automatically split one Excel row into two for pivot tabling purposes

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a series of accounting entries where each row has entries for multiple years.  Think:

```
Entry # | 2021  | 2022 | 2023 |  2024
  xxxx    $1.50  $2.50   $3.50  $2.50
  yyyy    $1.50  $2.25   $7.50  $8.50
```

Now, it turns out that each of those entries now needs to be allocated across sites, i.e. Site A, site B, site C. I have a percentage map - i.e.

```
Entry # | year | site A  | Site B | Site C |  Site D
  xxxx    2021    20%        30%       50%       0%
  yyyy    2021    0%         20%       30%      50%
```

What I really would like to do is *automatically* (automatically, since this process needs to be done every month) split this into a set of rows that could then be fed into a pivot table:

```
Entry # | Year  | Site |  $%
  xxxx     2021     A    $0.30
  xxxx     2022     B    $0.45
```

...

What is the best approach to this?  Is there a way to do it in excel using formulas?

Thanks!
/YGA

Comment: should be relativey straight forward, pseudo in your third table should be something like  $% = (2d lookup of first table entry x year) X (2d lookup of second table entry - year x site). Add rounding if needed. What else are you looking for?